# How can I stop user from navigating to the previous page

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a simple email portal as my college assignment and I refer gmail for various features.Now when we sign into a gmail account and then if we hit the back button of the browser we somehow still remain on the inbox page.In my case after login if I press back button I comeback to the login page.Please suggest how can I achieve this.Also I am a newbie to ASP.NET so keep it detailed

Comment: I think you should label this as homework.

Comment: try googling at least. Must have been asked a million times in forums and here...

Comment: I wouldn't really fit this in the homework category because 1. He is just looking for help on a particular feature of his project and 2. It's not his direct assignment to solve that problem, it's a problem with functionality he himself wish to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use javascript's "history.replace(...)" function:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript

In essence, you remove previous history entries.

Comment: I don't see how that helps here.

Comment: @sblom - read the title "how can i prevent user navigating to previous page." how can it NOT help?

Answer (score 4):

Very simple. When loading the login page, check the user's current session state, and if they're already logged in, redirect them to their inbox.